# How can I create default keyword arguments for a variadic function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variadic-functions, default-arguments

Suppose that we have a variadic function, such as the following:

```
def oofay(*args, **kwargs):
    return "\u2609_\u2609"
```

How can we set a default value for keyword argument "hamburg"?

One solution is as follows:

```
def oofay(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("hamburg", 99000)
    return "\u2609_\u2609"
```

However, I want default arguments which are evaluated at ***definition-time***, not ***call-time***.

Consider the following example:

```
color = "white"
get_fleece_color = lambda shoop: shoop + ", whose fleece was as " + color + " as snow."

print(get_fleece_color("Igor"))

# [... many lines of code later...]

color = "pink polka-dotted"
print(get_fleece_color("Igor's cousin, 3 times removed"))
```

The output is:

```
Igor, whose fleece was white as snow.
Igor's cousin, 3 times removed Igor, whose fleece was as pink polka-dotted as snow.
```

We don't want pink-polka dots in our variadic function, `oofay`. So.... how can we do it?

Comment: `def oofay(*args, hamburg=99000, **kwargs): ...`?

Comment: Just put `hamburg=99000` in the function signature, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [Azat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5997596/azat-ibrakov) and [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim)

```
def oofay(*args, hamburg=99000, **kwargs):
    return "\u2609_\u2609"
```